# How do I undo the Disable macOS Sonoma Text Insertion Point (Cursor) / Caps-lock Indicator command?

Tags: macos, terminal, preview, macos-sonoma

I ran this command in terminal that I found on here and it has led to my macbook laptop becoming very slow. It has now resulted in the system continually hanging.

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add 'redesigned_text_cursor:Enabled' bool false" /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain/UIKit.plist
```

How can I undo this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain/UIKit.plist redesigned_text_cursor -dict-add Enabled -bool YES
```

Then restart your Mac.
I'm not sure this will work...